which word in more precise in this scenario
how to specify the RED LINE portion? remaining portion?
any advice is appreciated!

Void space? Filled/remaining space?

"completely occupied or fitted in", Neither of these work. You also need to give a sentence that will show how you will use the word.

In order to be clear, you can just describe the area you mean: "The part above the slit"
